# Javascript returning promises with then callbacks

Tags: javascript, promise

I have recently seen this kind of pattern in a book ->
What is the value (data-type) being returned from a function if I return a Promise along with it's then callback:

```
function combineValues(p1,p1){
   return Promise.all([p1,p2])
           .then((d) => {
              return transformData(d);
           }
}
```

How can the return value of the above function combineValues be a promise?? We are already adding a .then at the end of something that is being returned.

And yet - below this code it was written

```
let p1 = fetch('url1'), p2 = fetch('url2');
combineValues(p1,p2)
  .then(v => console.log(`combined value is ${v}`))
```

If the 1st code snippet was only returning - Promise.all([p1,p2]) - then the 2nd code snippet is understandable - but it's returning

```
Promise.all([p1,p2]).then(something)
```

Comment: `.then` returns a promise ... that's what promise chaining is all about - because *nothing can turn asynchronous to synchronous* - not even quantum computing - by the way, your first code snippet is returning the result of `transformData(d)` as a promise

Comment: [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Return_value) - note that every single return value possible from a .then is a promise according to the *documentation*

Comment: got it - so a then callback is like a promise transform function - but still a promise - got it!!

Comment: I don't know what `a promise transform function` is, but `.then` *returns a Promise* is all that you need to know :p

Comment: it was a word - i just chained together - just like a function to take a resolved value of a promise and transform it to some other value

Answer (score 1):

`then` **always** returns a promise, by definition (and it *couldn't* return the resolved value: The resolved value doesn't exist at the time the code the return value is being passed to is running).

In the second example, you aren't looking at the return value of `then`, you are logging *inside* the callback.